# Unix / Linux file system

Tags: linux, unix

May i know why is it common practice to have the /etc folder at the root of the file system? Are there files in this directory that are important for the system to boot?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes.

Here is a good article about "FHS" - the "Filesystem Hierarchy Standard":

http://www.pathname.com/fhs/

Comment: thanks, it does not seem to explain why the /etc folder must be at the root of the drive tho.

Comment: @JohnMarston: Sure it does. Standard-conforming programs expect their configuration to be found under /etc - if you move /etc somewhere else they won't find it anymore.